# How to create an uninitialized variable in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

The code under inspection is a native Android library used in an Android application.
The decompiler is showing me a lot of lines in the style `DAT_12345678 = 0x12345678` with ascending addresses.
I know that this is the initialization of an uninitialized array.

When I want to set the data type, I get the error message `Address not found in program memory.`.

I guess I have to create a memory block first, but in the `Memory Map` window I do not see an option to add blocks.

How can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an uninitialized block of memory in the `Memory Map` window. Hit the little green "Add a new block to memory" button.

[image: Add a new block button]

Change the start address to an area not currently mapped, specify the length of the block you wish to allocate, and select `Uninitialized`.

[image: menu]